# execute shell script options

Tags: shell

I typically use `cd Directory/Directory/` to point to the shell directory and then type `bash shell.sh`, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to execute my shell & the location with one line?  I do bounce to different folders often.

Example:
unix folder with a shell script named alpha

```
cd Desktop/unix
bash alpha.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a script file executable:

```
chmod o+x alpha.sh
```

And include the appropriate shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) at the top, you do not have to invoke it with `bash`.  See `man chmod` for an explanation of `o+x`; you may prefer `a+x`.

As for the path, you can add that as per Rahul's suggestion, or you can do something similar without adding it to your $PATH, eg:

```
export SCRIPTS=~/Desktop/unix
```

Now anything executable in there can be used:

```
$SCRIPTS/alpha.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Set `PATH` in your system Environment 
eg.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/absolute/path/Desktop/unix
```

also you can put above line in `~/bashrc` file, then you don't need to set that path again

Note:- Your script should be executable in that location then you can run your script from any directory.

Refer [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-print-path-variable/) page for more information

Comment: I am familar with that method but that still doesn't solve if there is a folder within the defined path.  So after setting the path you would still have to do cd folder and run bash shell.sh.  I'm looking for a solution that can bounce to different directories AND execute the code within one line.

Comment: then set this `PATH=$PATH$( find $HOME/scripts/ -type d -printf ":%p" )`

Comment: refer this link for PATH with sub-directories http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657108/bash-recursively-adding-subdirectories-to-the-path

Comment: Another option is to symlink the contents of the subdirs, and place the link in the top-level dir.

Answer (score 1):

A answer with a different perspective, may help in better understanding of *nix environment.

All the commands/utilities you know of in *nux are present in some or the other directory which you can find using the `whereis`, or `which` command

#### Example

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ which sort
/usr/bin/sort
```

So, how these get located which you try to execute the command?

The answer is the `PATH` variable. If you do a `echo $PATH`, you'll see a colon `:` separated list of directories.

#### Sample output for $PATH

```
/home/mtk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin/:/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin
```

so, if you place your own executable at one of those locations, you'll be able to run it just as other system commands. Or, you can add your own defined directory to this list, by appending it to the `PATH` variable, and exporting it, so that it is available for the complete shell, like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/mtk/myUtilities/bin
```

You may want to add this particular line to `.bashrc` file, so that you don't need to execute the above command everytime you start the shell.

#### Just for fun

Ty changing the `PATH` variable, make it empty, you'll end up with useless shell, until you reset the `PATH` properly again.

```
$ export PATH=""
$ ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory
$ which pwd
bash: which: No such file or directory
```